# A constexpr function with delayed initialization of local variables

Tags: c++, constexpr

I am trying to write a `constexpr` function of the form:

```
constexpr int foo(bool cond) {
    int a, b, c;
    if (cond) {
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
        c = 3;
    }
    else {
        a = -1;
        b = -2;
        c = -3;
    }

    return a + b + c;
}
```

However, the compiler complains that I am using uninitialized variables, despite the fact that the eventual initialization of the local variables is guaranteed.

I could re-write the function to use ternary operators, that is, `int a = cond ? 1 : -1;`, etc., but I would prefer not to. Is there a way to convince the compiler that the local variables will be initialized?

Comment: With just a slight code duplication, you can move the `return a + b + c;` into each conditional branch and not have any declarations at the outer level.

Comment: `int a = 0, b = 0, b = 0;` ? ([no more error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b338b4c9fa495cc2)) (P.S: missed the edit window)

Comment: In C++, there is no such thing as "eventual initialisation". You either initialise your variables, or you don't. Whether you assign to them later is irrelevant. (In C and for compilers warning about "possibly uninitialised" it's different.)

Comment: You could just move the `else` values into initialization and then only change to the `if` values when `cond`.  (if it's actually a switch or many if/else's just initialize with the "fall-thru" values)

Comment: @BoPersson Unfortunately the return value is complex, and hence I would prefer not to duplicate it.

Comment: @AlessandroPower: does any of my solutions work for you? If not, what could I improve?

Comment: @Borgleader I would prefer to avoid an extra assignment.

Comment: @AlessandroPower: In a `constexpr` function?

Comment: @AlessandroPower keep in mind this is all compile-time so an "extra assignment" should have no overhead.  Bite my tongue, but this seems like a good time to use an old fashioned C-style macro.  They're compile-time too.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: why does it matter? It's a "conceptually wrong" unnecessary assignment.

Comment: @ebyrob: this is a **terrible** time to use an old fashioned C-style macro. Why on earth would you ever sacrifice type-safety and reasonable behavior for textual replacement?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: When you are faced with a choice between (a) one "conceptually wrong" assignment to an `int` that has exactly zero runtime cost and also no maintenance cost, and (b) a thirty line example of lambda/template/tuple magic that only three people in the world understand ... well, I know which one passes code review in my team. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I didn't know that an example using structured bindings, invocation of a lambda, and `std::tuple`'s constructor *(which has the almost the same number of lines as the original one)* was considered magic... Maybe you should read my answer again and also consider the "easier" *ternary operator + tuple* solutions which share all the benefits of the IIFE one but are easier to understand. I however strongly believe that the IIFE solution is idiomatic C++17 and not understanding it is due to a lack of knowledge of upcoming additions to the standard.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The function will not always be called with constant expression arguments, so the unnecessary initialization of a, b, and c may have a runtime cost. Admittedly the compiler will probably remove it though.

Comment: @AlessandroPower: Yes, even then it's completely a non-problem.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: Out in the real world you won't find many developers who find C++17 magic (yes, it's magic) to be innately familiar. Outside of academia and open-source, the real C++ world is barely up to C++03 level. And out of those who for whatever reason do, I imagine you'd still be in the minority thinking that such a solution were the most maintainable and supportable version. #KISS

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: that's exactly why I also provided C++14 and C++11-compliant solutions. C++17 is coming soon though *(and it will be **the latest standard**)*, so people should start to get used to it.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: Perhaps they should, but the vast majority won't. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm trying to do my part to avoid that! Acting like C++17 is magic that will never be used doesn't help :)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: I'm a realist! Anyway, as I said, it doesn't matter because the simplest solution is _still_ the right one. :)

Comment: Personally, I would prefer the ternary operator in this situation, but that's mainly because I find it clear & easily readable.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> However, the compiler complains that I am using an uninitialized variables, despite the fact that the eventual initialization of the local variables is guaranteed.

Initialize, or initialize not, there is no "eventual initialization." And, for `constexpr` functions, there is a requirement that, in [dcl.constexpr]:

> The definition of a `constexpr` function shall satisfy the following requirements: [...] its *function-body* shall be `= delete`, `= default`, or a *compound-statement* that does not contain [...] a definition of a variable of non-literal type or of static or thread storage duration or **for which no
>   initialization is performed**.

Can't have uninitialized variables in `constexpr` functions, which is what `a`, `b`, and `c` are for you.

So what can you do? You could just zero-initialize `a`, `b`, and `c`. That gets around this requirement. Or you could initialize `a`, `b`, and `c` inside of each scope in the `if`. Or you could defer to another `constexpr` function to do the summing:

```
constexpr int f(int a, int b, int c) { return a+b+c; };

constexpr int foo(bool cond) {    
    if (cond) {
        return f(1,2,3);
    }
    else {
        return f(-1,-2,-3);
    }    
}
```

There are lots of ways around this.

Comment: This is great.  Even if I **did** suggest a C-style macro to get around some limitations, all it would be doing, in essence, is choosing which function to call and how.  So why not have a wrapper `constexpr` function.  Perfect.

Comment: −1 not enough tuples

Comment: −1 not enough jQuery

Comment: −1 not enough dank memes

Comment: `auto [my_feelings] = []{ return std::make_tuple(hurt_t{}); }();`

Answer (score 14):

> However, the compiler complains that I am using an uninitialized variables, despite the fact that the eventual initialization of the local variables is guaranteed.

The standard requires all local variables in a `constexpr` function to be initialized.

> From [**§7.1.5**, par. 3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.constexpr#3)  *([[dcl.constexpr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.constexpr))*:
>
> > The definition of a `constexpr` function shall satisfy the following requirements: *[...]*
> >
> > its function-body shall be `= delete`, `= default`, or a compound-statement that does not contain *[...]*
> >
> > a definition of a variable of non-literal type or of static or thread storage duration or for which no initialization is performed. *[...]*
> >
> > ```
> > constexpr int uninit() {
> >     int a;     // error: variable is uninitialized
> >     return a;
> > }
> > ```

---

In C++17, you can use [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), [*structured bindings*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0144r0.pdf), and [IIFE *(immediately-invoked function expression)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to preserve your original structure:

```
constexpr int foo(bool cond) 
{
    const auto [a, b, c] = [&cond]
    {
        if (cond) 
        {
            return std::tuple(1, 2, 3);
        }
        else
        {
            return std::tuple(-1, -2, -3);
        }    
    }();

    return a + b + c;
}
```

Since your condition and branching is trivial, a *ternary operator* will suffice. The code snippet above may help you if in the future your initialization logic becomes more complex, but the one below should be good enough:

```
constexpr int foo(bool cond) 
{
    const auto [a, b, c] = cond ? std::tuple(1, 2, 3)
                                : std::tuple(-1, -2, -3);

    return a + b + c;
}
```

---

In C++14, you can use `std::make_tuple` and `std::get` instead:

```
constexpr int foo(bool cond) 
{
    const auto abc = cond ? std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3) 
                          : std::make_tuple(-1, -2, -3);

    return std::get<0>(abc) + std::get<1>(abc) + std::get<2>(abc);
}
```

---

In C++11 you can split the function in two smaller ones:

```
template <typename TTuple>
constexpr int sum3(const TTuple& abc)
{
    return std::get<0>(abc) + std::get<1>(abc) + std::get<2>(abc);
}

constexpr int foo(bool cond) 
{
    return cond ? sum3(std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3)) 
                : sum3(std::make_tuple(-1, -2, -3));   
}
```

[Barry's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509106/constexpr-function-with-delayed-initialization-of-local-variables/41509617#41509617) is definitely better if you decide to go down that route, though.

---

All the above solutions:

- Make your `a`, `b`, `c` variables `const`, which is always a good thing.
- Only perform a single check on `cond`, in order to closely resemble the structure of the code in the OP.

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote? My goal is maintaining the original structure without introducing any additional check on `cond`, adding `const` to `a`, `b`, `c` as an additional benefit.

Comment: I didnt downvote but all of the make the code a bit ugly compared to for example [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b338b4c9fa495cc2).

Comment: I didn't downvote either but you didn't actually explain what's wrong with the OP's code, and all your solutions are just more verbose ways of doing what the OP already admitted would be a last-ditch workaround. It seems they're after killing the problem at its source, instead.

Comment: @Borgleader: that gives the variables an useless "dummy intialization value" and prevents them from being `const`.
@LightnessRacesinOrbit: added a quote from the standard.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm quite sure that the OP's last-ditch workaround was having **3 separate** ternary expressions to initialize every variable. At least, that's what I can deduce from his last sentence.

Comment: So you're worried about the difference between clean zero and unknown values in a theoretical compile-time memory space that doesn't exist before the function assigns values based on `cond`?  In any case, I don't see how random memory is better than a known 0 in any situation.  (except if you're trying to dig through someone else's trash memory)

Comment: @ebyrob: there are no "unknown" uninitialized values in my solutions, and no extra unnecessary assignments/initializations/checks. This is what I would write even if `foo` didn't have to be `constexpr`.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I was referring to the OP's question which **does** have such values.  Your solutions are based on avoiding that pitfall.

Comment: @ebyrob I see now. It's not the `0` that bothers me the most, is the presence of unnecessary operations and most importantly the **unnecessary mutability** of the variables. Mutability should be minimized.

Comment: The C++17 code is very nice and would solve my problem well, but unfortunately I do not have access to a C++17 compliant compiler. The C++14 code is too ugly in my opinion, with all the calls to std::get. I gave this answer an upvote but ultimately I prefer Barry's solution.

Comment: @AlessandroPower: no worries, I think Barry's solution is good :)

Answer (score 1):

@Borgleader way is enough:

```
constexpr int foo(bool cond) {
    int a=0, b=0, c=0;
    if (cond) {
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
        c = 3;
    }
    else {
        a = -1;
        b = -2;
        c = -3;
    }

    return a + b + c;
}
```

compiles without error in C++11 and only warnings that *variable declaration in a constexpr function is a C++14 extension* and with no warning in C++14 mode (with CLang 3.4.1)

This is clean, simple to read and write and close to original code. But undoubtly, [@Barry's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41509617/3545273) is nicer.

Comment: I don't like this solution because it introduces an useless *"dummy initialization value"* of zero that is there only to please the compiler, and most importantly it prevents `a`, `b`, and `c` from being marked as `const`. Additionally, even though it compiles without error in C++11, it's not valid C++11.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: You are right, but I really though that Borleader's comment really deserved to be an answer.

Comment: @VittoriaRomeo I think a subjectively better way of writing it would be `int a{}` etc. No more zero.