# Performance loss when initializing variables in constexpr functions

Tags: c++, constexpr

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509106/a-constexpr-function-with-delayed-initialization-of-local-variables) it's impossible to leave variables uninitialized inside a `constexpr` function. Sometimes for performance reasons, we do not want to intialize variables though. Is it possible to "overload" the function somehow, so it allows for a `constexpr` version and a higher-performance non-`constexpr` function?

As an example, consider the following `add` function in a custom class `vec`:

```
auto add(vec that) const {
    vec ret; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        ret[i] = (*this)[i] + that[i];
    return ret;
}
constexpr auto add(vec that) const {
    vec ret = {}; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        ret[i] = (*this)[i] + that[i];
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: In most cases compiler will be able to optimize out the value initialization. So don't bother.

Comment: [`std::is_constant_evaluated`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated) might help.

Comment: `Sometimes for performance reasons, we do not want to intialize variables though` Classes are default initilaiized anyway, so there is no difference. You could only gain performance when omitting initialization on non-array and non-class types. And that's for most types like 1 instruction. For most architectures at most 2 instructions. You gain nothing. `does not default initialize` All class types are default initialized. Well, so you seem to be working with some custom `vec` class with some special semantics that you are interested in, please create an [MCVE].

Comment: @KamilCuk: Thank you for your clarification. My question is based on the wrong assumption that there could be a definition for `vec` such that it could be left uninitialized.

Comment: I dont completely understand the question. If you dont want to initialize the variable, then why declare it in the first place? In your example there is no difference betwee `vec ret;` and `vec ret{};`

Comment: @idclev 463035818: I didn't know that `vec ret;` and `vec ret{};` were the same. I was assuming in C++ there would be a possibility to allow variables on the stack to be left uninitialized and not zero-ed out, for performance reasons, but appearantly this is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ compiler is very good at optimizations, especially inside `constexpr` functions. The initialization will very likely be optimized and have no additional cost, and in your case it doesn't even matter since declaring a vector already initializes it to an empty vector.